# How to create button on Windows POSREADY 9 touch screen which will work as 'Alt+Tab' combination?

Tags: winapi, win32com

I have one POS system which is having configuration of **2 GB RAM, Dual Core processor**. POS Embedded windows is **POSREADY 9** and POS software is **VISTA 4.3**.

I don't want to give keyboard access on system (computer). Everything will be working using touch events.

In POS windows, we are running 2 applications.

1. POS SOFTWARE - VISTA 4.3
2. Browser Application.

I want to create a button on touch screen in windows 'POSREADY 9' which is having functionality of switching the windows. i.e. It will work as a 'Alt + Tab'.

Could you please guide me how to do this in quicker way?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a button?

Comment: My question is how to give functionality on that button? I never worked on windows applications So i don't have any idea about this.